# Create a master or main page

Tags: nodes

I want to know how to do is create a master or main page. I come from an ASP.Net background and am truly trying to learn Drupal, but I am very frustrated with finding where/how to start.

For me, the start has always been creating a main page. I use .Net as my platform but usually do all my work through HTML and CSS, as in creating a 3-column website using CSS. However, I really like the functionality of .Net in that I create this on ONE page as a master, and then just insert my content in a content holder. I know things don't work exactly the same, I don't expect them to, but I would like to know how to create a master page, or basically a template that contains the header, footer, menus and content layout.

How do I create a basic main page template?

Comment: That is the `page.tpl.php` file in most themes.

Comment: Pro Drupal Development (D6) or The Definitive Guide to Drupal 7 are both excellent texts to reference, too.

Comment: @Jimajamma Spooky! http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36627#comment-36731

Comment: @clive - insert Addams Family Theme Song here :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do some research into the way the drupal system works. Here is the documentation page for how to theme drupal. http://drupal.org/documentation/theme

If you are looking to create you own theme. For a beginner, it may be easier to start with a theme framework to mold it into what you want. Here are 3 of some of the more popular frameworks; [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen), [Fusion](http://drupal.org/project/fusion), and [Adaptive Theme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme).

P.S. - You may want to consider doing some basic google research prior to asking questions on here without more supportive information.

Comment: I did a search for "Master Page" and did not find anything. Sorry if I offended anyone because instead of asking for direct help I asked for a tutorial. From my days as ASP.Net forums they wanted you to read/watch tutorials before you asked for help. Things are different here. Very.

Comment: P.S. I guess the reason I am frustrated is because I don't like themes. I want to create my own theme. Not that I don't think some of the themes aren't excellent themes - they just aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might want to look into Theme frameworks like zen. They give you pretty much a blank slate to start building your OWN theme but with most of the building blocks for drupal in place. Similar to ASP but very different.

Comment: +1 if you are comfortable with HTML/CSS, then  you should pick up this zen subtheming tutorial, it's very easy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCg4sTA3DlQ

Comment: Thanks for the info and links. No, I know what themes are, but I honestly like to build my own. I like CSS, I just don't know HOW to do the changes in Drupal yet. And, I am having trouble getting my Administration Theme and my User theme to look the same. I don't know why I can't get the User theme to switch back to the Zen theme, which is what my Admin theme is - I even disabled the "Stark" theme but I can't get the User's theme to go back to looking the same as my Admin theme. Frustrated. Reading the "About theming" on Drupal.org and downloading Pro Drupal 7 Development e-book. Thanks!

Comment: Rule 0 of Drupal is that you should never edit any core themes or modules directly. This also applies to the vast majority of modules and themes contributed by the community as well. There's almost always a non-destructive way of accomplishing things. If you want to modify themes, for example, you would create a *sub-theme* and modify that instead.

Comment: @Ayliea What you wrote in your last comment is a different question. On Stack Exchange, comments when something about a post is not clear, not to ask further unrelated questions. Stack Exchange sites are not forums.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If using themes as template for a "Master" page isn't related to why my themes don't work correctly, then please pardon me. Opening multiple threads for pretty much the same issue (Themes/Master pages) isn't related then I will have so many questions on this board, if I ask every single question separately, I will end up flooding the board with questions! Which is why I originally asked for information about a good tutorial to get started. I admit - I am a COMPLETE beginner, and I am going to need a LOT of help. I appreciate all the help from those responding with suggestions.

Comment: @Ayliea, Its a Q&A Board! Fill'er Up! ..Just make sure you ask the questions properly as to fit the guidelines in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Ayliea Asking why you cannot set the theme seen from the users to the Zen theme is different from asking what the equivalent of a master page is. The fact you are asking a question about themes/master pages doesn't mean you can ask everything about themes/master pages in the same question, or in the comments for the answers you receive. Drupal Answers is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

[Panels Everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere/) allows you to create one or more "Site templates", which will usually contain things such as menues, footer, logo and similar. Then within it, you place the page specific content, which will be rendered separately.

> Panels Everywhere is an advanced method to completely do away with Drupal's restrictive blocks system and instead use the much more freeing Panels Layout system to control how your pages look. Panels Everywhere modifies the page as it is being rendered to 'wrap' the content in a display and can even take over your page theme to do away with the need for a page.tpl.php.
>
> Doing this requires that you set up a few things properly, because Drupal is not really designed for this kind of behavior. Be sure to read the [README](http://drupalcode.org/project/panels_everywhere.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/README.txt) before trying to use this module.

Comment: This is definitively what I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/front) module.

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on role. The pages can be of the following types:
>   1. Alias (only 2.x branch) - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown as the home page without redirecting the user.
>   2. Redirect - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
>   3. Themed - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed into the content area of a standard Drupal page.
>   4. Full - Allows for static content to be displayed to the screen as is. This method does not pass through Drupal's theming system.